# Initialize a state variable from observed object

Tags: state, swiftui, observedobject

I have another problem with the observable objects.

In  my View at the line "Position 1" I have the text view for editing the address (and save it into the state property "text", which have to be displayed in the view).
The state variable "text"  has to be initialized from the class LocationObserver property "currentAddress". 
I just tried to set the  initialization of the view 
Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Best

Dragan

```
The View 


struct PickFoto: View {
    @ObservedObject var observeLocation = LocationObserver.shared()!
    @State private var address = LocationObserver.shared()?.currentAddress ?? " "

...    

TextView(text: $text, isEditing: $isEditing) // Position 1


Text("current Address (observeLocation): \(observeLocation.currentAddress)") // Position 2
...
}

The Shared Object

class  LocationObserver: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    // This published property value  has to be the initial value   
    // for the TextView (the property $text. how to to this??)

    @Published var currentAddress = " " 

    static var instance: LocationObserver?

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 52.516861, longitude:13.356796)

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let currentLocation = locations.last?.coordinate



        convertGPSToAdress(coordinates: locations.last ?? defaultLocation,
                           completion: { (retStr: String) in
                                            self.currentAddress = retStr // set the  @Published property
                                            print("currentAddress in EscapingClosure: \(self.currentAddress)")
                                            //everything is fine
                                        }
        )

    }


    func convertGPSToAdress(coordinates: CLLocation,
                        completion:  @escaping(String) -> ()) -> () {

    let address = CLGeocoder.init()
    address.reverseGeocodeLocation(coordinates) { (places, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if places != nil {
                let place = places?.first
                completion(formatAddressString(place: place!)) // returns a formatted string address 
            }
        }
    }
}

    ....
}
```

Comment: Have you implemented your own `TextView` View? Could you show the code of it?

Comment: Hello Aleksey, the problem is independent from the TextView (s. bellow). Best, Dragan

Comment: Dragan, I was wrong, please excuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following (code snapshot not testable - so just scratchy)

```
struct PickFoto: View {
    @ObservedObject var observeLocation = LocationObserver.shared()!
    @State private var address: String

    init() {
        _address = State<String>(initialValue: LocationObserver.shared()?.currentAddress ?? " ")
    }

    ...
```

**Update:** synchronise private `address` state with external

```
var body: some View {
    ...
    TextView(text: $text, isEditing: $isEditing) 
       .onReceive(observeLocation.$currentAddress) { newAddress in
            self.address = newAddress
       }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello Asperi, yes thats the right way to initialize the state variable. Thanks a lot! 
But now I have a similar problem: The variable address is not set to the address calculated in "convertGPSToAdress" because the escaping closure (label "completion:") is over after "your" initializer of address in the struct PickFoto. Any Idea?

Thanks in advance!
Dragan

Comment: @user11646889, you can synchronise private `address` state by subscribing to publisher, attached to any view within body, as shown in updated answer.

Comment: Hi Asperi, great! I wanted only to initialize the adress which has to be edited - its now always updated - not a big problem, I can set it in the closure only it it hasn't be edited. Thanks a lot, you solved my problem, if you come in Berlin, the first beer's on me.PS in which documentation can I  find this aspects of SwiftUI?

Comment: @user11646889, pleased to hear. If it the answer works for you it is good-citizen practice here on SO to vote it up and mark accepted to make it more visible for other community who have same problem. Thanks.